# TextBox does not rebind to object replaced by ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am getting weird behavior when I bind to `ObservableCollection`. If the collection changes during setting value through binding in `TextBox`, the `TextBox` will not bind to the new object but remain bound to the old one (which is now invalid).

### Detailed description to reproduce the problem

1. Start app
2. Edit `TextBox` of item of your choosing (and click away so the change is updated to source)
3. The setter of the `ItemVM` updates the backing collection, which in return fires event notifying the `View` that item is replaced
4. The `TextBlock` and the **other** `TextBox` is successfully rebound to the new item in the collection, but the `TextBox` you used to edit this item is still bound to the old `ItemVM`
5. If you try to edit value again using **the same** `TextBox`, it fails (because the item no longer exists in the collection)
6. If you try to edit value using **the other** `TextBox`, the first `TextBox` is rebound and working again, but now this `TextBox` is broken
7. You can edit `TextBox`es how many times you want, but you must always alternate between them

I think, this happens because the original `TextBox` is executing code, so it ignores the changed value, once it finishes executing that code, it again listens for the binding events and simply rebinds itself to the new object.

**The question is:** how do I prevent this?

**PS:** this example is really simplified, in real scenario the `ItemVM` does not update the collection directly, but some generic object - not known until runtime might, so suggestions of type "do not update collection there" are irrelevant.

Feel free to ask, I will try to include additional info.

### Complete source code

#### Code

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1 {

    class Program {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            var dc = new VM {
                Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemVM>(),
            };

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                dc.Items.Add(new ItemVM(i.ToString(), dc));
            }

            var w = new MainWindow {
                DataContext = dc,
            };

            new Application().Run(w);
        }
    }

    class VM {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Items { get; set; }
    }

    class ItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public VM ParentVM { get; set; }

        string value;
        public string Value {
            get { return value; }
            set {
                int index = ParentVM.Items.IndexOf(this);
                ParentVM.Items[index] = new ItemVM(value, ParentVM);
                this.value = value + " in old VM";

                var h = PropertyChanged;
                if(h != null)
                    h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }

        public ItemVM(string value, VM parent) {
            this.value = value;
            ParentVM = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

#### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohit's solution works, but then it is not possible to use validation. I came up with 2 solutions.

### Use Binding.IsAsync

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, IsAsync=True}" />
```

It works essentially the same as invoking asynchronously in property setter. Since this is built-in feature, it is more clear what were the author's intentions and therefore easier to maintain.

In addition, since .NET 4.5 we can implement interface `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and have validation working even on asynchronous bindings.

### Raise ObservableCollection's events asynchronously

This solution works on pre .NET 4.5 and allows to use `ValidatesOnExceptions` in addition to `ValidatesOnDataErrors`, which is the only option for the first solution.

Property setter is called synchronously, also the binding is used synchronously (`IsAsync=False`). The difference is, that the bound `ObservableCollection` must invoke events asynchronously. It can be done by wrapping `ObservableCollection` in class similar to this:

```
class MarshaledObservableCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, IWeakEventListener {
    readonly IEnumerable<T> backingCollection;

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged {
        add {
                var info = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandlerInfo {
                Handler = value,
                Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher,
            };
            collectionChangedHandlers.Add(info);
        }
        remove {
            var info = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandlerInfo {
                Handler = value,
                Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher,
            };
            collectionChangedHandlers.Remove(info);
        }
    }

    readonly List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandlerInfo> collectionChangedHandlers = new List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandlerInfo>();

    public MarshaledObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection", "collection is null.");

        var obs = collection as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (obs == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("collection must be INotifyCollectionChanged", "collection");

        backingCollection = collection;
        CollectionChangedEventManager.AddListener(obs, this);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return backingCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        foreach (var item in collectionChangedHandlers) {
            //Important line - invoking asynchronously with the DataBind priority
            item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(item.Handler, DispatcherPriority.DataBind, sender, e);
        }
    }

    public bool ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (managerType == typeof(CollectionChangedEventManager)) {
            OnCollectionChanged(sender, (NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)e);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    struct NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandlerInfo {
        public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
        public NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler Handler { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `DataContext` completely of `TextBox` to which it is bound to. So, I suspect while updating bound property of earlier DataContext, textBox is not able to pick new DataContext.

What you can do is **put the updating of newer DataContext on UI dispatcher asynchronously so that all UI components can pick up the update in DataContext** including the one which is getting update. i.e. queue the collection update code on UI dispatcher asynchronously.

```
public string Value
{
    get { return value; }
    set
    {
        int index = ParentVM.Items.IndexOf(this);
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate  <-- HERE
        {
            ParentVM.Items[index] = new ItemVM(value, ParentVM);
        });
        this.value = value + " in old VM";

        var h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}
```